# Import photos from Time Machine backup of other machine, without losing metadata

Tags: backup, time-machine, photos

I replaced my MacBook and I have the Time Machine backups from my old laptop, but I'd like to start the system fresh, importing only the files I really need and re-installing all the programs manually, I'm basically copying and pasting the files I need.

Both `Photos` and `High Sierra` are the same version in my old machine and my new one.

My problem is that I can't find a way to import my pictures from `Time Machine's Photos Library`, since `Photos Library` is not just copy and paste like regular files.

**I tried: Copy Photos Library from Time Machine and paste in my new Pictures folder**

Didn't work, even though I opened photos app pressing option and selected the new Library. The following error pops-up: `An error occurred while repairing permissions` – which makes no sense, since I was using the same version of Photos before.

I know I could open masters and import JPEGs, but in this way I'll loose the location/date of my pictures.